# Очень смущает двоеточие, не подойдёт ли зап/тире?

Tags: пунктуация

> Для тех, кого не столь заботит величие развалин, для тех, кто
>   предпочитает пение птиц, заросли роз и зелень кипарисов: продолжайте
>   движение по via del Monte Oppio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что "продолжайте движение по" здесь лишнее, а точка с запятой — к месту:

Для тех, кого не столь заботит величие развалин, для тех, кто предпочитает пение птиц, заросли роз и зелень кипарисов,— via del Monte Oppio.
Или:
Те, кого не столь заботит величие развалин, те, кто предпочитает пение птиц, заросли роз и зелень кипарисов,— продолжают движение по via del Monte Oppio.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве варианта:

Но те, кого не столь заботит величие развалин и кто предпочитает пение птиц, заросли роз и зелень кипарисов, — те могут продолжить движение по via del Monte Oppio.

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит как приказ для тех, кто...

Как вариант изменений:

Тем, кого не столь заботит величие развалин, кто предпочитает пение птиц, заросли роз и зелень кипарисов, — мой совет: продолжайте движение по via del Monte Oppio.